# how to regexp positive lookaheads in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to filter as regexp like "(?=nkf)(?=bom)" in MySQL.
This example regexp works in PHP, JavaScript and other.
This regexp means both words include "nkf" and "bom".

I try the regexp in WordPress MySQL.

```
AND post_title REGEXP "(?=nkf)(?=bom)"
```

But I receive an error: `Error Code: 1139. Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp`

Can I use such regexp, in other words, positive lookaheads?

Comment: What do you mean by "both words".  Please show some strings that should / should not match.

Answer (score 0):

I've suspect that PHP used the `PCRE` regular expressions by Philip Hazel while mysql used the `REGEXP` by Henry Spencer. They have different syntax so acceptable in the PHP can be malfunctioning in the mysql.

Answer (score 0):

[MariaDB-10.0+](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/pcre/#positive-and-negative-look-ahead-and-look-behind-assertions) has a PCRE look ahead/behind features as it uses PCRE natively.

Answer (score 0):

Just use below line instead of yours.

```
AND post_title REGEXP "([^>]nkf)([^>]bom)"
```